# Change thousands of user roles in wordpress with sql

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

My WordPress website, over the years, accumulated thousands of Contributors, BBPress Participants (I don't have BBPress anymore), and a lot of spammy and malicious users, I found the hard way.

I want to change all of the roles to Subscriber except for the Administrator (me). I researched online and installed plug-ins that change role capabilities. But, I want to do the following with SQl or PHPMyAdmin:

1. Delete all emails with *.ru, *.nl, and other non-USA email addresses
2. Change all of the 30,000 + members to Subscriber
3. Delete inactive users who have not logged in or contributed for 90 days.

`SELECT wp_users WHERE ...`

There is no role column in this table and I can't find it in phpMyAdmin; however, in the admin panel of WordPress, I see it.

I found a lot of great SQL queries in articles online, but none that discuss deleting all of the users with a particular attribute such as a top-level domain name, changing all user roles who are Contributors to Subscribers, or just deleting all users who have not posted content in a certain amount of time. I don't want to try anything on my own that will damage the database.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can find the user roles in the wp_usermeta table, there with the entries: e.g:

a:36:{s:13: "administrator"; ...

Unfortunately it's not that you just manipulate a value in a column in the wp_user... that would be nice....

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, you will be able to post comments.